# UI DataBinding Only Updating when Initiated from Method Inside ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

The desired flow of my project is:

1. Button click on UI triggers timer start.
2. Each timer tick changes the string bound to TextBox text.
3. UI updates to the new string automatically.

For a long time I thought I had a databinding problem because the UI wasn't updating, but then I found if I triggered the timer start via the view model rather than externally via main window code behind, the UI updated just fine. However this isn't the desired behavior, and I'm trying to understand why that's the case.

Full view (`TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"` is the property being updated):

```
<Window x:Class="MaterialDesignTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignTest"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
    TextElement.FontSize="13"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" 
    TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"        
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}">

<materialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="RootDialog" Loaded="DialogHost_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Width="100" x:Name="SearchRestore" Margin="0 150 0 0" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}" materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogClosingAttached="SearchRestore_OnDialogClosing" 
                Content="Restore" Click="SearchRestore_Click">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="Restoring..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 15"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock.DataContext>
                                <ns:ProgressViewModel />
                            </TextBlock.DataContext>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <Button Name="CircleButton" Margin="0 50 0 0" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="{Binding IsSaving}"
                        materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.Value="{Binding SaveProgressButton}">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Height="24" Width="24" Foreground="White">
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="materialDesign:PackIcon" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:PackIcon}}">
                                        <Setter Property="Kind" Value="CloudSync" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSaveComplete}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Kind" Value="Check" />
                                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.8" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </materialDesign:PackIcon.Style>
                            </materialDesign:PackIcon>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Full view model (commenting out `KickOffProgressTimer();` causing the UI to no longer update property **FileName**):

```
    using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MaterialDesignTest
{
    public class ProgressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer progressTimer;

    private string _fileName;
    public string FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _fileName)
            {
                _fileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
            }
        }
    }

    private double _saveProgressButton;
    public double SaveProgressButton
    {
        get { return _saveProgressButton; }
        set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _saveProgressButton, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    private bool _isSaveComplete;
    public bool IsSaveComplete
    {
        get { return _isSaveComplete; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _isSaveComplete, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    private bool _isSaving;
    public bool IsSaving
    {
        get { return _isSaving; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _isSaving, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    int progress = 0;
    int cycles = 0;
    public ProgressViewModel()
    {
        KickOffProgressTimer();
    }
    public void KickOffProgressTimer()
    {
        progressTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        progressTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(progressTimerTick);
        progressTimer.Interval = 140;
        progressTimer.Start();
    }

    private async void progressTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (progress < 100 && cycles < 2)
        {
            if (progress == 99)
            {
                cycles++;
                progress = 0;
            }

            FileName = SelectRandomString();

            IsSaveComplete = false;
            IsSaving = true;
            progress++;
            SaveProgressButton = progress;
        }
        else
        {
            IsSaveComplete = true;
            IsSaving = false;
            progressTimer.Stop();
            progressTimer.Enabled = false;
            SaveProgressButton = 0;

            await NonBlockingDelay(1750);

            DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand.Execute(null, null);
        }

    }
    async Task NonBlockingDelay(int value)
    {
        await Task.Delay(value);
    }



    private Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> RaisePropertyChanged()
    {
        return args => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    static string SelectRandomString()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var filenames = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\System32\"));
        int index = random.Next(filenames.Count);
        return (filenames[index]);
    }
}

}
```

Logic to kickoff timer in main window code behind:

```
private void CircleButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressViewModel pvm = new ProgressViewModel();
        CircleButton.DataContext = pvm;
        pvm.KickOffProgressTimer();
    }
```

Comment: Use WPF's DispatcherTimer instead of a WinForms System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

Comment: have you tried removing all that async/await stuff? Usually having async stuff running in your UI thread is a good recipe for your UI not being updated. Also have you tried setting a breakpoint in your `FileName` property to see if the `OnPropertyChanged` part is executed/reached?